# Sending UDP packet upon interupt

Tags: c++, embedded, mbed

I'm trying to send a UDP packet when an interrupt is triggered using the mbed platform.

However, when i try to call `udp_send` from the interrupt function `key_pressed`, i get **sys_arch_protect error.**

Could this be because some portion of UDPsocket is not being passed to the interrupt function?

For the sake of brevity i have omitted most of the code

Thanks in advance,
Greg

```
/*--INCLUDES----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "mbed.h"
#include "EthernetInterface.h"


/*--CONSTANTS---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
const int BROADCAST_PORT = 58083;
char pin_status[1] = {0};
InterruptIn push_button(SW3);

/*--FUNCTION DEFINITIONS----------------------------------------------------------------*/
void udp_send(void);
void keyPressed(void);
void keyReleased(void);

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void keyPressed(void)
{
    printf("Key Pressed\r\n"); //debug
    udp_send();     //calling the function to send UDP packet, this casuses errors
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void keyReleased( void )
{
    printf("Key Released\r\n"); //debug
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void udp_send(void)     //sends UDP broadcast packet
{
    UDPSocket sock;
    sock.init();
    sock.set_broadcasting();
    Endpoint broadcast;
    broadcast.set_address("255.255.255.255", BROADCAST_PORT);   //broadcast UDP to all
    sock.sendTo(broadcast, pin_status, sizeof(pin_status)); //pin_status changed elsewhere
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main() {
    EthernetInterface eth;
    eth.init();
    eth.connect();
    printf("IP Address is %s\r\n", eth.getIPAddress());
    udp_send();     //test call to confirm UDP_send function is working (with Wireshark)

    while( 1 )
    {
        push_button.rise(keyPressed);   //debounce omitted, calls interupt
        push_button.fall(keyReleased);
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know "mbed", but in general there are very serious restrictions on what it's safe to do from within application level code during an interrupt - a small set of functions known as "async signal safe".  For POSIX systems, search for the title "Async-signal-safe functions" on [this page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).  While many UDP operations are safe (including the sending), your `UDPSocket` class can't safely use e.g. `malloc`, which might be triggered from `new`.  As an experiment, try a global `sock` initialised in `main` and only a send in `udp_send`.

Comment: Thanks for you response Tony,

As you suggested, i tried added the `init()` into the main function and just had `sock.sendto...` in `udp_send`

Unfortuneatly still getting the `sys_arch_protect error` but with an additional `sys_mbox_post error`

Comment: Yikes.  Googling, seems `sys_arch_protect` fronts a high speed recursive mutex of sorts; an error therewith inside the `udp_send` suggests deadlock, and that your `udp_send` is not async signal safe.  What's commonly done in signal handlers is setting of some `volatile` flag variable that the interrupted thread can check periodically to perform whatever action you want logically tied to the interrupt.  So, `void udp_send(void) { global_flag = 1; }` and at `//other stuff` put `if (global_flag) {  global_flag = 0; ...send...; }`.  Use `atomic_int flag`/`++`/`--` if 1:1 interrupts:sends needed.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks @Tony d, i guess its not good practice to include big function calls within the interrupt routine anyway.

For future reference, code is attached;

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "EthernetInterface.h"
#include "rtos.h"
#include <string>
#include "PinDetect.h"

/*--CONSTANTS---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
const int BROADCAST_PORT = 58083;
char pin_status[1] = {0};
int global_flag;

InterruptIn push_button(SW3);

/*--FUNCTION DEFINITIONS----------------------------------------------------------------*/
void udp_send(void);
void keyPressed(void);
void keyReleased(void);

EthernetInterface eth;
Endpoint broadcast;
UDPSocket sock;

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void keyPressed(void)
{
    printf("Key Pressed\r\n"); //debug
    udp_send();
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void keyReleased( void )
{
    printf("Key Released\r\n"); //debug
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void udp_send(void)
{
    global_flag = 1;        //sends UDP broadcast packet
        //pin_status changed elsewhere
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main() {
    eth.init();
    eth.connect();
    sock.init();
    sock.set_broadcasting();

    broadcast.set_address("255.255.255.255", BROADCAST_PORT);   //broadcast UDP to all
    printf("IP Address is %s\r\n", eth.getIPAddress());

    udp_send();     //test call to confirm UDP_send function is working

    while( 1 )
    {
        push_button.rise(keyPressed);   //debounce omitted, calls interupt
        push_button.fall(keyReleased);
        if (global_flag)
        {
            global_flag = 0;
            sock.sendTo(broadcast, pin_status, sizeof(pin_status));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should still make `global_flag` `volatile` to ensure `main()` doesn't use an in-register copy and not notice the in-memory value changed asynchronously....